# Ionic2,Jasmine,Karma unit test

Tags: jasmine, ionic2, karma-jasmine

We are setting up a unit test framework for our Ionic2 project
while running npm test , we are faced with the following error.
I give below the src/*.ts and src/*.spec.ts alongwith  the cmd window error
Please help resolve

> Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR: Error{rejection: 'Failed
>   to load app.html', promise : ZoneAwarePromise{__zone_symbol__state: 0,
>   __zone_symbol__value: 'Failed to load app.html'}, z one: Zone{_properties: Object{}, _parent: null, _name: '',
>   _zoneDelegate: ZoneDelegate{_t askCounts: ..., zone: ..., _parentDelegate: ..., _forkZS: ..., _forkDlgt: ..., _interceptZS: .. ., _interceptDlgt: ..., _invokeZS: ..., _invokeDlgt: ...,
>   _handleErrorZS: ..., _handleErrorDlgt : ..., _scheduleTaskZS: ..., _scheduleTaskDlgt: ..., _invokeTaskZS: ..., _invokeTaskDlgt: ...,
>   _cancelTaskZS: ..., _cancelTaskDlgt: ..., _hasTaskZS: ..., _hasTaskDlgt: ...}}, task: ZoneTask{ runCount: 1, type: 'microTask', zone: Zone{_properties: ..., _parent: ..., _name: ..., _zoneDel egate:
>   ...}, source: 'Promise.then', data: undefined, scheduleFn: undefined,
>   cancelFn: null, ca llback: function () { ... }, invoke: function () {
>   ... }}}
>
> Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) DashboardService should return a
>   non empty array FAILED TypeError: Cannot read property 'assertPresent'
>   of undefined at resetFakeAsyncZone
>   (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/karma-typescript-bundle
>   -66485eOt1ZMUGTWZ.js:143884:22) at Object. (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/karma-typescript-bundle
>   -66485eOt1ZMUGTWZ.js:144536:13) Error: ProxyZoneSpec is needed for the async() test helper but could not be found. Plea se make sure that
>   your environment includes zone.js/dist/proxy.js at runInTestZone
>   (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/karma-typescript-bundle-6648
>   5eOt1ZMUGTWZ.js:143659:19) at Object.
>   (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/karma-typescript-bundle
>   -66485eOt1ZMUGTWZ.js:143633:17) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of null at Object.
>   (src/pages/dashboard/dashboard.spec.ts:47:35 <- src/pages/das
>   hboard/dashboard.spec.js:40:31) Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0):
>   Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.019 secs / 0.003 secs

---

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { App, Config, Form, IonicModule, Keyboard, DomController, MenuController, NavController, Platform ,NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { DashboardPage } from './dashboard';
import { ConfigMock } from '../../mock';
import { AzureDatasync } from '../../app/providers/azure-datasync';


let dashboard = null;
 let navCtrl: NavController; 
 let navParams: NavParams;
 let datasync: AzureDatasync;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardPage> = null;
let instance: any = null;
describe('DashboardService', () => {

  //  beforeEach(() => {
 //     dashboard = new DashboardPage(navCtrl,navParams,datasync);
   //   console.log(dashboard);
   // });

      beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DashboardPage],
      providers: [
        App, DomController, Form, Keyboard, MenuController, NavController, Platform,
       {provide: Config, useClass: ConfigMock},
      ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardPage);
      console.log(fixture);

      instance = fixture;
      console.log(instance);
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  }));
    it('should return a non empty array', () => {

            let result = dashboard.getData();
             console.log(result);
            expect(Array.isArray(result)).toBeTruthy;
            expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        }
    );



});
```

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AzureDatasync } from '../../app/providers/azure-datasync';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';

/*
  Generated class for the Dashboard page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
})
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {
  todays: any ;
  ticklers: any;
  cases: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public datasync: AzureDatasync) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {

    this.todays = [
        {type: "abc", name: "test", duration: "9.30 AM - 10.00 AM"},
        {type: "def", name: "test2", duration: "12.45 AM - 3.10 PM"}
    ];

    this.ticklers = [
        {name: "abc", description: "A Court "},
        {name: "def", description: "dd"}
    ];

    this.cases = [
        {name: "Msh", duedate: "Due on 7th Dec", priority: "PsI", timeduration: "24hrs", imgurl:"_blank.png"},
        {name: "ss Smith", duedate: "Due on 11th Dec", priority: "Pris", timeduration: "30 mins ", imgurl:"./person_blank.png"}
    ];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Jasmine and Karma.

In my karma.conf I loaded some additional files into the browser:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js', // 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Zone is not defined'
      '../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js', // 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined'
      '../node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js', // 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined'
      '../node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js', // 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined'
      // ANY OTHER FILES TO LOAD FOR YOUR TESTS
    ],
```